# dynamically added images not getting added on page when toggel function in Jquery is used

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is code to add images in Javascript.

```
function AddFirstRow() {
    //Create an input type dynamically.
    var element ;
    var seatArr = document.getElementById("seatArr");

    //Assign different attributes to the element.
    var  rowCounter ;
    for( rowCounter = 1 ; rowCounter < 8 ; rowCounter++ ){
        element = document.createElement("input");
        element.setAttribute("type", "image");
        element.setAttribute("src","../Images/available_seat_img.png") ;
        element.setAttribute("class", "seatRightMostRow1");
        element.setAttribute("id", "1V");
        seatArr.appendChild(element);
    }
}
```

Body elements where images are added.

```
<div class="seatArr">        
    <span id="seatArr" >&nbsp;</span> 
    <input type="image" class="seatRightMostRow1" id="1A" alt="sfdsf" src="../Images/available_seat_img.png"  />
    <input type="image" class="seatRightMostRow2" id="1B" alt="sfdsf" src="../Images/available_seat_img.png"  />
</div>
```

JQuery for toggel feature on image.

```
$("input[id]").toggle(function(){
    $(this).attr("src","../Images/selected_seat_img.png");
},function(){
    $(this).attr("src","../Images/available_seat_img.png");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on the order in which you wire things up.

If I ensure that the images are inserted before I wire up the `toggle` handlers, they toggle works for all images:

```
$(function(){
  AddFirstRow();
});

$("input[id]").toggle(function(){
  $(this).attr("src","../Images/selected_seat_img.png");
},function(){
  $(this).attr("src","../Images/available_seat_img.png");
});
```

If I move the call to `AddFirstRow` to happen after the `toggle` is wired up, it will indeed only trigger for the initial images.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/frankvanpuffelen/HPPKv/1/

Normally you can use jQuery's `on` to set up a handler that will trigger on dynamic elements too, but I'm not sure how that works with `toggle`. I'll check.

**Update**

This code uses the `on` function to ensure the handler fires for dynamic elements:

```
$(".seatArr").on('click', 'input', function(){
  $(this).attr("src",
    $(this).attr("src") == "../Images/selected_seat_img.png"
    ? "../Images/available_seat_img.png"
    : "../Images/selected_seat_img.png"
  );
});
```

Comment: Thanks Frank,just now changed the order of functions.Previously I was calling AddFirstRow() function on onclick event of button. changed the order toggle and AddFirstRow().It is working now.. Also I need clarification on how to bind data to this dynamic images.. Actually I'm trying to create a bus seat layout, user may select a seat from dynamically generated images. Do I need to post that separately.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "binding data to dynamic images". If it is a different and concrete question, by all means ask it separately. I'd suggest however to first learn more about why the ordering matters and how `on` (and its predecessor `live`) work for your situation.